# python 3 ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, rss, feed

I'm new in Python. I can not understood the error .I followed a tutorial to write the code.But it's not working

code is available in this link

http://pythonprogramming.net/scraping-parsing-rss-feed/

Comment: I **didn't** downvote this question, but to avoid downvotes in the future please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, post your own code with your question, and avoid linking to code on external sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> The `urllib2` module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`.

The page you link to is using Python 2.  If you want to use Python 3, you will probably have to change things to make it work.

Comment: This should be one of the things that [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) can fix automatically. (Although you should always look over the output rather than trusting it to be magic, of course.)

Comment: Actually, I see that the very next line in the docs you linked already says that, so I probably didn't need that comment. :)